# ООП python и с++

Tags: python, c++, ооп

Учусь в университете, и у нас ЯП с++. Особо не понял как с его ООП работать, но примерно было так:

```
class Students
{
    Students(){};
    Students(string surname, string name, string lastname)
    {
        this->surname = surname; 
        this->name = name; 
        this->age = age
    }
};
```

В питоне получилось так:

```
class Students:
    def __init__(self, surname, name, lastname):
        self.surname = surname
        self.name = name
        self.lastname = lastname


def main():
  std1 = Students()
  std1.surname = "Test"
  print(std1.surname)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Еще при создании экземпляра класса, вылезает ошибка, что не ввел данные в параметры конструктора `__init__()`.

Когда в свою очередь, в С++ не нужно заполнять параметры конструктора когда объявляешь экземпляр класса.
Можете объяснить пожалуйста? Очень надеюсь что мой вопрос поняли.

Comment: В C++ вы создали конструктор, не принимающий никаких аргументов, а в Python вы никакого аналога не сделали, в вашем методе `__init__` все аргументы обязательные

Comment: https://docs-python.ru/tutorial/opredelenie-funktsij-python/znachenie-argumenta-umolchaniju-funktsijah/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В Python для того чтобы сделать аргументы при создании класса не обязательными нужно сделать так:

```py
class Students:
    def __init__(self, surname = None, name = None, lastname = None):
        self.surname = surname
        self.name = name
        self.lastname = lastname
```

По сути мы даем параметрам значения по умолчанию равным None